# How to get User information of the Oauth authenticated user from Google & Twitter?

Tags: python, twitter, oauth

I have authenticated the user with oauth on both twitter & Google and have access_tokens.

(Using Python)

But,

How to get the information about this authenticated user ?

Eg:
Name, Age, Email, gender, etc.

Comment: By editing the post to remove the part where you asked about a Twitter API, it makes my answer about Twitter look random and out of context. You may want to add that back in so that people who come across this question in the future understand what was asked and what the response was.

Comment: I rolled the edit back for this reason.

Comment: Ok.. no problem.
I understand.. Good work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Twitter, I'd suggest using the [tweepy library](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy). It provides a nice Python API for accessing all the data you can get back from Twitter, such as [user data](http://packages.python.org/tweepy/html/api.html#user-methods).

If you want to do it yourself, you'd want to look at the docs for Twitter's REST API, specifically the [User resource](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show). I don't think you can get such personal information as age, email, gender from the API at all, however.

Comment: Well, REST API did the trick for Twitter.
NOw, can you tell something for Google ?

Comment: Since my answer was helpful, I'd appreciate it if you could upvote it by clicking the up arrow to the left.

Comment: given.. but no one specifically asks for that. :)

Answer (score -2):

Google is more complicated since it has many APIs for different things. This Python library supports a bunch of them: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/

Comment: I know about that, but not able to find - which one will give me the details of the user himself.